# Acceder a los nombre de los campos de un archivo JSON

Tags: jquery, json

Estoy tratando de hacer una tabla dinámica a partir de un archivo JSON. El problema está en que quiero que las cabeceras de cada columna sea el nombre del campo. Es decir, yo tengo el fichero JSON:

```
"articulos": [
    {
        "nombre": "Camiseta",
        "talla": "XL",
        "descripcion": "100% Algodon"
    }]
```

Pues necesito que la primera fila de la tabla sea "`nombre`", "`talla`" y "`descripcion`". He buscado por todas partes pero solo encuentro como acceder a los atributos. Agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: `Object.keys(objeto_json)`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Me ha funcionado a la perfeccion y ya me estaba volviendo loco :)

Answer (score 0):

puedes recorrer los datos de esta forma

```
<script>
var miJSON={
    "A1":{"valor":"100", "color":"azul", "caracteristica":{"tipo":"S1"}},
    "A2":{"valor":"110", "color":"rojo", "caracteristica":{"tipo":"S2"}},
    "A3":{"valor":"120", "color":"negro", "caracteristica":{"tipo":"S3"}},
    "A4":{"valor":"90", "color":"verde", "caracteristica":{"tipo":"S4"}},
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var table="<table><tr><td>Id Registro</td><td>Valor</td><td>Color</td><td>Caracteritica</td></tr>";
    $.each(miJSON, function(i,item){
        table+="<tr><td>"+i+"</td><td>"+miJSON[i].valor+"</td><td>"+miJSON[i].color+"</td><td>"+miJSON[i].caracteristica.tipo+"</td></tr>";
    });
   table+="</table>";
   $('#anyDiv').append(table);
});
</script>
```

Yo haría directamente esto para generar la tabla